# Why NONE of bluetooth headset work on ANY of my PC even though they ALL works on my phones?

Tags: audio

It works fine on my android phones.

The headset works great too on everything.

However, this is what happen if I use sound recorder to record stuff on my pc

https://clyp.it/3kr5545o

That's the sound.

I am trying to say hello hello 123 and then the sound is just like grunts.

In fact, that website, has an option where I can record sounds. Again no sound show up.

So if I try to say `hello hello 123` I either got grunts or no sound at all.'

I tried different bluetooth headset and different website

http://vocaroo.com/

NONE of them works. They all fail to record sounds.

Do I need to do something special so I can use bluetooth headset for my PC?

Update: My surface pro 2 has bluetooth capability straightaway. My bluetooth mic works fine there.

http://vocaroo.com/

Update: turns out it doesn't work on vocaroo too. I thought it works because surface pro 2 has built in microphone and vocaroo must have used that. I ensured that the default recording device is the bluetooth headset and it doesn't work.

It looks like I have to do something special to allow bluetooth headset as mic.

I wonder what.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check/rule out:

- Can you record properly from a wired headset/mic?
- What are the volume, mic boost and quality settings on your audio input?
- Are you listening to the audio via the bluetooth device as well?

Comment: haven't tried 1st. but yes I am listening to the audio via the bluetooth device as well

Comment: To start with, then, I would check how the audio comes out off of a different output, like the build in speakers.  And check the volume, boost, and quality settings, and if you have the same problem with a wired mic.

Comment: The audio pops out fine. It seems that I need to do something before I can use bluetooth mic for PC. I have no idea what that something is.